# send_keys from a function in Python and Selenium

Tags: python, function, selenium, sendkeys

I have this function:

```
def add_key():
    driver.find_element_by_name('key').send_keys('first_bonus')
    driver.find_element_by_name('translation').send_keys('First Bonus')

...

add_key()
```

Now I want to be able to send_keys and rename them in the future ('first_bonus' and 'First Bonus') when calling the function itself `add_key()` not inside the function. But I don't want the `send_keys("")` to be visible when caling the function, just the name of the key and translation. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you just add arguments in the function header, and use `send_keys(argument_1)` for example?

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm still learning so didn't think of this! Helped me a lot!

Comment: No problemo, glad to be of help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you need to make it dynamic with arguments

```py
def add_key(element_name, text):
    driver.find_element_by_name(element_name).send_keys(text)
add_key('key','first_bonus')
```